# Sapphire Radeon RX 570 buzzing noise under load

Tags: gpu, amd-radeon, noise

I have just bought Sapphire Radeon RX 570 Pulse GPU card and though fans are perfectly silent, the card emits a relatively low pitched humming noise under DirectX load. It does not come from fans, because it stops for a moment entering menu, switching scenes etc. It changes depending on the FPS value, tested in on Rainbow Six Siege and MSI Afterburner and changing V-Sync to 2, 1 or OFF clearly changes the intensity of humming (30 / 60 / 100 FPS). It resembles rather a so called coil whine. It is not very loud.

Is this normal by these cards or should it be replaced?

Comment: It's normal. Even of the fans are designed to be silent, there is significant airflow when at load.

Comment: @overmimd The sound is not made by air but by coil whine. Wondering if it becomes worse or better if I exchange for msi rx 570 or 1060, if it gets worse or better overtime. There are many opinions in forums.

Comment: Written as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to RMA the card. The reseller had a very good exchange policy, so I got MSI Armor 1060 6GB OCV1 (+80 USD) which had best references. First tried to google everywhere, but coil whine seems to be a lottery connected to both GPUs and PSUs and affecting all brands and chips and getting a card that would do absolutely zero noise is impossible I guess.

The result is, that coil whine did not go away completely, but **it is better on this card with lower power consumption and lower PSU requirements**. So I am glad that I did RMA although the coil whine from that AMD card was not that terrible, but now it is considerably better. One reason could have been, that I had run a card with recommended PSU 500 W on PSU 450 W.

Trying another GPU card was worthwhile in this case though it did not remove the whine completely.

Answer (score 1):

Should not be a problem; changing the card is not needed.

The champions of such coil noise were the [970s](http://wccftech.com/nvidia-gtx-970-coil-whine/) and they were in most cases fine .

The actual coil noise level is related also to the PSU. So unless you also want to test various PSUs, just ignore that noise.

Limiting the FPS to the monitor's supported values seems to help that noise, according to AMD, MSI and nV.

Comment: What are the chances that it gets worse/better over time?

Comment: Limiting FPS using V-sync changes the frequency of the sound, I have specified that in the question.

Comment: Do you have yourself experience with various relevant cards having and not having coil whine or is this recommendation a result of google search ? - because there you can find many varying opinions.

Comment: I have tested enough models. One example of solved coil noise was switching the PSUs of a Radeon and GeForce card. After switching the PSUs between them, both cards had very low to almost no noise compared to the initial values. That leads me to conclude that the PSU design is related to this.

Comment: I have Enermax Triathlor ECO 450W Bronze, it should be a good PSU.

Comment: It's not about good or bad, in my case both were good PSUs, they just behaved differently with different setups. Probably also the VRMs in the MB matter in this case.